# Prove that ∫f<lim inf ∫ f_n where f_n>=0 and f_n→f in measure

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that ∫f< liminf ∫f_n  where f_n>=0 and f_n→f in measure

That is one of my real analysis HW problem. I think it looks like Fatou's Lemma but still don't know how to do it. Any hint is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are on a finite measure space.  Do you know that if $f_n\to f$ in $\mu$ that there is a subsequence so that $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e.$[\mu]$?  Can you use this result?